# Behaviour of function consisting of various compositions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

We denote by $B_2(0)$ to be the open ball of radius $2$ centered at $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with standard euclidean metric.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function such that $||f(x)-x||\leq 100$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Define $g:B_2(0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ by

$g(x)=\frac{2f(\frac{x}{2-||x||})}{1+|f(\frac{x}{2-||x||})|}$.

Show that if $||x||\rightarrow 2$ then $||g(x)-x||\rightarrow 0$

I think this is intuitive though I am having hard time showing using standard epsilon $N$ arguments.  If $||x||\rightarrow 2$ then I think $|f(x)|\rightarrow 2$.

I thought that the 100 was a red herring but as the answers shows, it relied on the fact that the constant was 100.

I tried looking at $||g(x)-x||$ this gave me: $|\frac{2f(u(x))-x-x|f(u(x))|}{1+|f(u(x))|}|$ where $u$ is $\frac{x}{2-||x||}$, but I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $f(x)=x+h(x)$ where $\|h(x)\|\le 100.$ Thus for $u={x\over 2-\|x\|}$ we get $$g(x)={{2x\over 2-\|x\|}+h(u)\over 1+\left \|{x\over 2-\|x\|}+h(u)\right\|}\\ ={2x+(2-\|x\|)h(u)\over 2-\|x\|+\|x+(2-\|x\|)h(u)\|}\\ ={2x\over 2-\|x\|+\|x+(2-\|x\|)h(u)\| }\\ +{(2-\|x\|)h(u)\over 2-\|x\|+\|x+(2-\|x\|)h(u)\| }$$ The second term $S(x)$ tends to $0$ as the numerator tends to $0,$ while the denominator $D(x)$ tends to $2.$ Next the first term $T(x)$ satisfies $$\|T(x)-x\|={\big| \|x\|-\| x+(2-\|x\|)h(u)\|\big|\,\|x\|\over D(x)}$$ The numerator tends to $0,$ while $D(x)$ tends to $2.$ Hence $$\|g(x)-x\|\le\|S(x)\|+\|T(x)-x\|$$ tends to $0,$ when $\|x\|\to 2^-.$